# Why doesn't Apache server MAMP run?

Tags: php, apache, mamp

I've downloaded php5.6 from here https://www.mamp.info/en/downloads/ and added it to php folder. After that I can't run Apache server. I removed that folder, but Apache still doesn't work. Files in /Local/logs/ are empty.
Mac OS Mavericks.

Comment: Here's a screenshot: http://joxi.ru/4AkoPzliMy0dKA

Comment: Did you replace the existing php installation ? MAMP should already come with php 5 I think

Comment: There's a typo: I've downloaded php5.6 and I didn't replace anything, just added a folder.

Answer (score 0):

Same problem here. A (temporary) solution is to start apache from the terminal:

```
sudo /Applications/MAMP/Library/bin/apachectl start
```

MAMP detects it as its status light becomes green! But I cannot explain why MAMP doesn't command apache anymore, with nothing logged.
Tried to modify file /bin/startApache.sh, adding a `sudo` before start command, without success.